# Setting focus when control's top level parent window is the active window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a C# project. The issue is that background events like mouse-enter make a background window pop out in focus when it is not the active window. The solution strategy is to add preventive steps before setting this focus.

My attempts include the following strategy:

Prior to the `control.Focus()` call, I want to implement a condition involving the [`GetActiveWindow()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx) to match the control's top level parent's associated window handle. For the latter I am using [`Control.TopLevelControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). But, every time I do this, I get `null` for this property. The reason as per the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) is that the control is not parented on a form.

Attempted snippet:

```
if (myControl.TopLevelControl.Handle == GetActiveWindow())
{
     this.myControl.Focus();
}
```

Background for the code: This code is not owned by me. So, pardon me for being abstract. I will try to be as elaborate as possible. The concerned control is a private member custom layout panel that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Panel where the DoubleBuffered property is set to true. This control has been added to a internal partial class that inherits from UserControl (Windows Forms). The latter control has been added via a private member SplitContainer (Windows Forms) on a public partial class (inherits from User Control too).

In the constructor of the user control for this layout panel, the even is added as:

```
myLayoutPanel.MouseEnter += this.myLayoutPanel_MouseEnter;
```

The event without my change looks like:

```
private void myLayoutPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
        myLayoutPanel.Focus();
        myLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

Also, I manually watched on the handles for the control's parent hierarchy and was never able to get a match to the active window handle. Intuitively, I feel the `GetActiveWindow()` uses interoperability to delve into the unmanaged code to get the handle while the top level property stays in the managed zone and thus has its limits. I might be wrong though.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: `events like mouse-enter make a background window pop out in focus when it is not the active window`  That's not actually normal behavior.  Do you have code running in the MouseEnter event that would bring the form into focus?

Comment: You are not exactly helping us help you when you don't tell us why you have user controls that are not embedded in a form.  Guessing: don't do anything when myControl.IsHandleCreated is false.

Comment: Are you sure, that your window (form) is realy active? The window/form can be on top (even if is not top-most) and be inactive.

Comment: @Gaurav Sinha **myControl** created by dynamic or design?

Comment: @LarsTech, yes the code brings the control to focus. There is no associated form. The control is a custom control built.

Comment: @HansPassant, I apologize. I don't know the reason yet. I just know when I debug and check this.myControl.findForm(), I get null. I am fairly new to this technology.

Comment: @BaskarJohn, they are being added with Controls.Add. I guess then that it is dynamic. So, it is a part of a chain of a user control hierarchy.

Comment: @TcKs, when I use Form.ActiveForm, even that returns null. :( I feel as all these user controls are dynamically added via Controls.add, it might be the problem.

Comment: In winforms (and in Win32 UI) is everything added dynamically. It's not the problem. The problem is, that your form does not have focus. The problem will be elsewhere. I think it will be something in the "mouse-enter" area. Try elaborate this part, we can probably help.

Comment: @TcKs, So, inside the event, when I watch or use methods like FindForm or the property GetTopLevel parent, they get me null. The control is a layout panel which extends the table layout panel and resides on a custom user control. This is a whole nesting of user controls. But all user controls should be hosted by a form, right? I see the controls add property being used as well.

Comment: In Winforms, you have no way how to show control wihtout form. But! In with native Win32, there is no problem to show control outside the form.

Add more of your code into the question, so I can see it. Without that, I can barely help more than now.

Comment: @TcKs, as this code is not owned by me, I need to be as abstract as possible. However, I will be elaborate without giving away original code. The concerned control is a private member custom layout panel that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Panel where the DoubleBuffered property is set to true. This control has been added to a internal partial class that inherits from UserControl (Windows Forms). This control has been added via a private member SplitContainer (Windows Forms) on a public partial class (inherits from User Control too). Does this give you more info or is it still vague?

Comment: As I said - the composition of controls is not important. Create minimum sample of code, which (doesn't) work. My tip (without knowing the full code) is the part with handling mouse events and poping up the form. Not the composition of controls in the form.

Comment: @TcKs, got it. I am appending the info on the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two levels of "focus". One is "focus" of [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) inside form. And one is "focus" of [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) inside whole composition of windows on desktop.

The [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) use these members:

- [CanFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.canfocus(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ContainsFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Focus()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Focused](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [GotFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx)

The [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) use these members:

- [Activate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Activated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you sets focus to control inside the form (via [Focus()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)), the focus is scoped only to the form, and form state is not changed. If you want also sets focus to form, you need activate (via [Activate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)) the form.

This minimal code to reproduce this behaviour is:

```
public class MyControl : FlowLayoutPanel {
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private TextBox textBox2;

    public MyControl() {
        this.textBox1 = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);

        this.textBox2 = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);

        this.BackColor = Color.Blue; // not required

        this.MouseEnter += this.MyControl_MouseEnter;
    }

    private void MyControl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.textBox1?.Focus(); // sets focus to the control

        var parentForm = this.FindForm();
        parentForm?.Activate(); // activates the form
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, in my app, the FindForm() returns null. I believe at the heart of the root hierarchy it is making a COM level C++ call and not basing off of a form. I was just checking that. It is strange to fathom user controls without a base form.

Comment: Your conditions are unusual. I really want to help you. But I need more clues. Can you produce some code which will be similar to your conditions?

Comment: Exactly, I'm curious about your question too, and I have been reading @TcKs comments from the beginning. You don't have to share your exact code _which you don't own_. Just keep excluding the parts that have nothing to do with the problem until you have the minimal code that **reproduces the issue**, then you can either share that or create a similar example _making sure that it also reproduces that behavior_. Otherwise, it's difficult to guess the cause of your issue.

Comment: @TcKs, I figured my problem. No solution though. My top level control that hosts this layout panel has a window handle. And this control is on a base application framework. My top level control uses COM interfaces to get the handle created. I cannot get the COM level window handle from any property on C#. Sorry for the confusion guys. I have not done this before. There is a very fine policy about NDA. So, I wasn't able to convert it into a fluid flow. But, I appreciate the help you have given.

Comment: @TcKs and everyone: Thanks for all the help. The issue was resolved by using the API call WindowFromPoint instead of using the control to get the parent window.